Waydroid network interface in bridged mode possible?
Original Problem: I got my repaired phone back. In the meantime I had used waydroid to do all stuff. Now I want to transfer everything from waydroid to the phone by using the google method. However google on waydroid can't see the phone in the network. I assume this is because waydroid is accessing the LAN via NAT.
Could I solve this issue by putting the interface into bridge mode, and if so, how can I do that?
addendum
When I wrote google method I refer to this:
When I start up my repaired and blank phone it asks me if I want to migrate from another phone. I say yes and it tells me to open google app on the old phone, enter „mein Gerät einrichten“ in the search field of the google app. (maybe it's "setup my device" in English). The old phone should then find the new phone within the LAN or WLAN and connect to it.

Sorry but what do you mean by "google method"? Backup and restore via GDrive? But for restore via GDrive the local network topology doesn't matter, just internet access is required.

@Robert I enhanced my question accordingly.

Doesn't Way Droid support bridged networking mode instead of NAT? That should make it possible to be in the same network with a physical Android phone. The other options would be USB or Bluetooth which both most likely will not work. But don't expect too much from this data migration system, when I used it, most apps weren't migrated with data.

@Robert as it is somehow a full grown container system I think it must support bridging somehow, mustn't it? But I'm still searching documentation. However documentation seems sparse to me.
